# Immediately a Task for a call that's constructed inside a ContinueWith block?

Tags: c#, .net, task

First off, apologies for the title; I couldn't really think of how to succinctly articulate what I'm trying to do.

I have the following two functions:

**Main code:**

```
private async Task<PreparationInfo> PrepareRoundtrip()
{
    PreparationInfo output = new PreparationInfo();

    Task.Delay(3000); // stands in for a call to the server to fetch data for how to prepare

    prepare(output) // package result into output

    return output;
}

private Task ExecuteWithPrepare()
{
    if (!PrepareEnabled) // instance variable
        return stateObject.Execute();
    else
    {
        Task<PreparationInfo> prepareTask = PrepareRoundtrip();
        return tceTask.ContinueWith((prepareTaskInternal) =>
        {
            stateObject.Execute(); // this is the Task that I need to return
        });
    }
}
```

**stateObject.Execute() header:**

```
internal Task Execute()
{
    ...
}
```

I'm writing a wrapper for the `stateObject.Execute()` method that will optionally call a preparation method (`PrepareRoundtrip()`) beforehand to process some parameters before executing.

If preparation is not enabled (`PrepareEnabled == false`), I can just call `Execute()` direction and immediately return the Task it returns.  If preparation *is* enabled, I need to run the preparation method (which is unique to this task, I can change it however necessary), then run `Execute()`.

The part I'm stuck on is this:

The entire function needs to run and return as though `stateObject.Execute()` was called directly, just with the `PrepareRoundtrip()` part added, meaning two things:

1. The Task that gets returned from `ExecuteWithPrepare()` needs to represent the Task that `stateObject.Execute()` returns.
2. `ExecuteWithPrepare()` needs to return immediately (i.e. *not* wait for the 3 second delay in `PrepareRoundtrip()`

What's the best way to achieve this?  Thanks!

**TL;DR:**

Adding a wrapper for `stateObject.Execute()` to add an extra preparation step that's potentially lengthy; need the whole thing to return a Task representing the original result immediately rather than waiting for the preparation step to complete first.

Comment: You never await `Task.Delay(3000);` in your example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ContinueWith` at all. It's an outdated method with dangerous behavior (specifically, it will use the current task scheduler).

Instead, just use `await`:

```
private Task ExecuteWithPrepareAsync()
{
  if (!PrepareEnabled)
    return stateObject.ExecuteAsync();
  else
    return PrepareAndExecuteAsync();
}

private async Task PrepareAndExecuteAsync()
{
  await PrepareRoundtripAsync();
  await stateObject.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Also note the `Async` naming convention, [part of the TAP pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Comment: `stateObject.Execute()` is not an async method despite returning a Task; should it still be named `ExecuteAsync`?  It was written before async-await was a thing.  I _really_ wish I could rewrite the entire stack to properly use async-await instead of this bastardized and outdated Task structure...

Comment: @Benjin: If it is compatible with `await`, then it should be named `ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: I explain more in depth [on my blog (see example at the end)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). The problem is with how the code is used: for most code, `ContinueWith`-style code will either run on the thread pool or a UI *TaskScheduler* - but `await`-style code will either run on the thread pool or a UI *SynchronizationContext*. `await` is safer because it captures the SynchronizationContext in preference to the TaskScheduler.

Comment: @Benjin If the method returns a `Task`, then it's asynchronous, and the `Async` suffix is appropriate.  How it goes about making itself asynchronous (whether it uses `await` or not) is an implementation detail of that method not relevant to its callers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Unwrap` to turn a `Task<Task>` (which is what you have there) into a `Task` representing the completion of the inner `Task`, without synchronously waiting for the outer task to finish.
2. Just `await` the `Task<Task>` twice, instead of once, if in an `async` method.